# Automatically close all the other <details> tags after opening a specific <details> tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

Here is my code.

```html
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>
  Demo 1
</details>

<details>
  <summary>2</summary>
  Demo 2
</details>

<details>
  <summary>3</summary>
  Demo 3
</details>
```

What I want to do is -- if the details of any single `<details>` tag is open and I open/view another `<details>` tag, then the earlier one should close/hide/minimize.

How can this be achieved?

I'm aware the `<details>` tag is not supported in IE or Edge.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Another approach, slightly shorter, slightly more efficient, [without dependencies](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), and without onclick attributes in the HTML.

```js
// Fetch all the details element.
const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

// Add the onclick listeners.
details.forEach((detail) => {
  detail.addEventListener("toggle", () => {
    if (detail.open) setTargetDetail(detail);
  });
});

// Close all the details that are not targetDetail.
function setTargetDetail(targetDetail) {
  details.forEach((detail) => {
    if (detail !== targetDetail) {
      detail.open = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>Demo 1
</details>

<details>
  <summary>2</summary>Demo 2
</details>

<details>
  <summary>3</summary>Demo 3
</details>
```

Comment: Listening to 'click' will not detect keyboard interaction. Use MutationObserver instead.

Comment: @geek-merlin I believe it does. I don't know if it is following spec, but it works on FF, Safari and Chrome as far as I have seen.

Comment: @ Quentin Roy You are right. Browser magic going on.

Comment: Opposite: `.setAttribute("open", true)`

Comment: @geek-merlin the `toggle` event also works with keyboard interaction (see my answer below)

Answer (score 24):

**Whao !**  <sup>before my posting...</sup>

1. No one has ndicated that `<details>` elements work with the `toggle` event?
   -- instead of `click`
   -- and the `toggle` event also works with keyboard interaction.
2. No one has indicated that the `open` attribute is a **boolean**,
   make it to `true` or `false`,  don't do a <del>`.removeAttr("open")`</del> ;)

the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

```js
const All_Details = document.querySelectorAll('details');

All_Details.forEach(deet=>{
  deet.addEventListener('toggle', toggleOpenOneOnly)
})

function toggleOpenOneOnly(e) {
  if (this.open) {
    All_Details.forEach(deet=>{
      if (deet!=this && deet.open) deet.open = false
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>
  Demo 1
</details>

<details>
  <summary>2</summary>
  Demo 2
</details>

<details>
  <summary>3</summary>
  Demo 3
</details>
```

> The same thing in a shorter way with ES10? => `.ontoggle` direct event method

```js
document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach((D,_,A)=>{
  D.ontoggle =_=>{ if(D.open) A.forEach(d =>{ if(d!=D) d.open=false })}
})
```

See it in action : ( Plus some CSS improvements ;)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach((D,_,A)=>{
  D.ontoggle =_=>{ if(D.open) A.forEach(d =>{ if(d!=D) d.open=false })}
})
```

```css
details {
  border        : 1px solid lightgrey;
  width         : 24em;
  padding       : 0 .6em;
  border-radius : .3em;
  margin        : .3em;
  }
details > summary  {
  font-weight   : bold;
  margin        : 0em -.6em;
  list-style    : none;
  display       : block;
  padding       : .5em;
  }
details[open] {
  padding-bottom : .6em;
  }
details[open] summary {
  border-bottom : 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom : .6em  ;
  }
summary::marker {
  display : none;
  }
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display : none;
  }
summary::after {
  display    : block;
  float      : right;
  content    : '\1405';
  cursor     : pointer;
  transition : 180ms;
  transform  : rotate(90deg);
  }
details[open] > summary:after {
  transform  : rotate(-90deg);
  }
summary:hover {
  outline          : none;
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum one</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, 
  dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas 
  ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, 
  enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat.
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum two</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, 
  dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas 
  ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, 
  enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat.
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum three</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, 
  dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas 
  ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, 
  enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat.
</details>
```

Comment: +1 for `open` attribute instead of `removeAttribute("open")` (which sets `open` to false as a side effect), upvoted also for library-free javascript and toggle event. I recommend `getElementsByTagName` instead of slower `querySelectorAll` and cleaning the global scope which I solved in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65674567/343721) as a build up on this one.

Comment: Agreed... +1 for vanilla JS. I'm trying to break away from jQuery, so this answer (and  @JanTuroň 's answer below) are quite illuminating in showing the long and shorter versions.  Thanks! Can your code be tweaked to incorporate a separate button/function that will close all details on the page?

Comment: Awesome @MisterJojo - Thanks!  I needed to add some curly braces in the forEach statement.  Not sure why.  My snippet looks like this:
---
`function killButton(){
   document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach(d=>{d.open=false});
}`

Comment: @JJ. or `const killButton=_=>document.querySelectorAll('details').forEach(d=>d.open=false);` in ninja code

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#events) states that `toggle` event is dispatched only after the `open` attribute switches, but not before. But here, we are attaching the event listener to toggle itself. So how is this working?  This is supposed to be a chicken and egg problem, right?

Comment: @Pardhu I suspect faulty reasoning. Events on open.value changing are related. On a rational basis neither of them precedes the other.  And in any case, js ccde can't dispatch a user event, which rules out any possibility of conflict and creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 17):

Same concept, just a bit shorter.

```
$('details').click(function (event) {
    $('details').not(this).removeAttr("open");  
});
```

Comment: Usually, in cases like this, all the `<details>` are siblings, so we can do this:

`$('details').on('click', function(event) {
      $(this).siblings('details').removeAttr('open');
});`

Comment: Probably not the fastest, but definitely nice readable code!

Answer (score 7):

Yet another answer for those who don't want to use [obsolete jQuery](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=should+i+use+jquery) and those who loves functional javascript

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName("details")].forEach( (D,_,A) =>
  D.addEventListener("toggle", E =>
    D.open && A.forEach(d =>
      d!=E.target && (d.open=false)
    )
  )
)
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>Demo 1
</details>

<details>
  <summary>2</summary>Demo 2
</details>

<details>
  <summary>3</summary>Demo 3
</details>
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can set the same `name` attribute value in mutually-exclusive `details`

```html
<details name="topic">
  <summary>Exclusive topic 1</summary>
  <p>Exclusive topic 1 details</p>
</details>
<details name="topic">
  <summary>Exclusive topic 2</summary>
  <p>Exclusive topic 2 details</p>
</details>
```

Comment: It works since Chrome 120, Opera 106 and Safari 17.2, not yet for Firefox, see the compatibility table in the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#name).

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution. Please correct me if this is a wrong approach.

I added an onclick event to all of the details tag and made a function `thisindex(this)` which returns the index of the clicked tag and the obtained index number is then passed to the another function `closeAll()` which minimizes/closes all the other open tags except for one whose index matches with what we obtained earlier.

Here is the code.

```js
function thisindex(elm){
  var nodes = elm.parentNode.childNodes, node;
  var i = 0, count = i;
  while( (node=nodes.item(i++)) && node!=elm )
    if( node.nodeType==1 ) count++;
  return count;
}

function closeAll(index){
  var len = document.getElementsByTagName("details").length;

  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(i != index){
      document.getElementsByTagName("details")[i].removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<details onclick="closeAll(thisindex(this));">
  <summary>1</summary>Demo 1
</details>

<details onclick="closeAll(thisindex(this));">
  <summary>2</summary>Demo 2
</details>

<details onclick="closeAll(thisindex(this));">
  <summary>2</summary>Demo 3
</details>
```

Same with the help of `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('details').click(function (event) {
    var index = $('details').index(this);
    var len = $("details").length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
      if(i != index){
        $("details")[i].removeAttribute("open");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Kindly suggest me a better approach if this not up to the mark.

Comment: `<details>` tag has an attribute called `open`. If that attribute is given then the detail tag is already open. So in this case I am used javascript to simply remove that attribute so as to close the tag.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'm not javascript guru, but is there not a way to target the atribute open? This seems more complicated, did you find a simpler solution? I've tried it and it works so that is good enough. I just ask if there is a simpler method

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("details[open]")` will select all the `details` tags that are currently opened.

Answer (score 0):

Modification for use with polyfill jquery-details.js [Edge]

```
  var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
  var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
  const details = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("details"));
  details.forEach((targetDetail) => {
    targetDetail.addEventListener("click", () => {
      details.forEach((detail) => {
        if (detail !== targetDetail) {
          if(isEdge) {
            detail.className = detail.className.replace(/\bopen\b/g,"");
            detail.open =  false;
            detail.querySelector("summary").setAttribute("aria-expanded","false");
            var chil = detail.querySelectorAll("details > *");
            for(var j = 0; j < chil.length; j++) {
              if(chil[j].tagName != "SUMMARY") {
                chil[j].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          } else {
            detail.removeAttribute("open");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...
I would like to point out this quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

> **Note**: You have to remove this attribute entirely to make the details hidden. open="false" makes the details visible because this attribute is Boolean.

(Read the **note** appended right at the end of the *attributes* paragraph.)

Apparently, in this case **boolean** means *existing or not* and not *settable to true or false*...

Browser magic going further!

Comment: Yeah, that section doesn't make much sense to me — if it's boolean, then why doesn't it being `false` work...?

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/600#issuecomment-265004120 is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions offered appear less than clear to me.
Consider this instead:

```js
const closeDetails = event => {
  const targetDetails = event.target.parentElement;
  const openDetails = document.querySelectorAll('details[open]');
  for (const details of openDetails) {
    if (details === targetDetails) continue;
    details.removeAttribute('open');
  }
};

const summaries = document.querySelectorAll('summary');
for (const summary of summaries) {
  summary.addEventListener('click', closeDetails);
}
```

This production version follows the same thought process but is extended to cater for multiple accordions, and reduces the number of event listeners:

https://codepen.io/2kool2/pen/poOgxKb