# close detail if another detail HTML5 element if opened

Tags: html, user-interface, summary

I'm using the new HTML5 element of `detail` and summary together. This is for a FAQ section, so there are several questions. It works fine, but I need an extra functionality... If the user opens a second detail element the first detail element stays open, which can be disturbing. I would like to make this detail close once another is opened.

I also doubt if this is user friendly?

Here you have an image which illustrates what I mean and would like to avoid.

[image]

Here you go some code with what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/782HX/

Comment: Without code (including your attempts to solve this) it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @PeeHaa I inserted a jsfiddle. Its simply the basic layout of details and summary.

Comment: I don't understand why so negative points given... I thin its a normal  question to do and well described.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily with jQuery.

```
$('details').click(function(event) {
    $('details').not(this).removeAttr("open");  
});
```

This closes all other details except the one that is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

For any person who is intersted I found an answer... I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/html5-automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specifi):

If you add `onclick="closeAll(thisindex(this));"` to each detail and add this javascript it will close the open detail when another details is opened. Hope it helps!

```
function thisindex(elm){
  var nodes = elm.parentNode.childNodes, node;
  var i = 0, count = i;
  while( (node=nodes.item(i++)) && node!=elm )
    if( node.nodeType==1 ) count++;
  return count;
}

function closeAll(index){
  var len = document.getElementsByTagName("details").length;

  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(i != index){
      document.getElementsByTagName("details")[i].removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }
```