# Click expand with details and summary tag

Tags: html, css

I'm using click expand collapse using `<details>` and `<summary>` tags.
It can expand and collapse without problem.
I want to expand one information only one time.

What I meant is,
when I click information1 it will expand, and again click information2.
then information1 collapse and information2 expand.
it means only one can  expand in one time.

How can I do this with only using css

```
<details>
  <summary>Information1</summary>
    If your browser supports this element, it should allow
    you to expand and collapse these details.
</details>
<details>
   <summary>Information2</summary>
    If your browser supports this element, it should allow
    you to expand and collapse these details.
</details>
<details>
   <summary>Information3</summary>
    If your browser supports this element, it should allow
    you to expand and collapse these details.
 </details>
 <details>
    <summary>Information4</summary>
     If your browser supports this element, it should allow
     you to expand and collapse these details.
  </details>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/mjxhj5se/

Thanks..

Comment: how are you expanding for now ?

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mjxhj5se/ you can see it here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically close all the other <details> tags after opening a specific <details> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai)

Comment: Right now it is only possible to remove the open tag in details with js. There is a way to achieve what you want only using css but not with details and summary.

Answer (score 4):

This cannot currently be done with `<details>` and `<summary>` using only CSS, because CSS can't manipulate an HTML element's attribute – in this case, the `open` attribute. However, if you don't need to use `<details>` and `<summary>`, the [solution](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-css-based-content/) linked by [CasperSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718047/click-expand-with-details-and-summary-tag/40694666#comment66736040_39718272) works well for your purpose.

Or you could add this jQuery to achieve the wanted effect with `<details>` and `<summary>`:

```js
$("details").click(function(event) {
  $("details").not(this).removeAttr("open");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Summary 1</summary>
  Some details 1.
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Summary 2</summary>
  Some details 2.
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Summary 3</summary>
  Some details 3.
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

might not be possible to achieve this with css alone. Please have a look at;

[Automatically close all the other <details> tags after opening a specific <details> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using jQuery here is one easiest tutorial [Simple jQuery Accordion](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/)

Comment: Yes, i want to do it by using css. that's the problem.

Comment: here is the solution http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-css-based-content/