# Expandable navigation with details and summary

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use `<details>` and `summary` instead of buttons for an expandable navigation.

Consider this markup:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <details>
        <summary></summary>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit eos tenetur saepe, provident vitae, illum. Similique nemo ullam ipsam fuga vero quam inventore officiis quibusdam, mollitia reiciendis, atque quos. Ex.
      </details>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and this css:

```scss
li {
  &:first-of-type {
    border-top: 1px solid tomato;
  }
  border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
  position: relative;
}

summary {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid maroon;
}
```

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
  position: relative;
}

li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid tomato;
}

summary {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid maroon;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <details>
        <summary></summary>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit eos tenetur saepe, provident vitae, illum. Similique nemo ullam ipsam fuga vero quam inventore officiis quibusdam, mollitia reiciendis, atque quos. Ex.
      </details>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

when the `<details>` is open it works except the `<summary` is in the top of the `<li>` which is not right. If I add `bottom: 0;` to make it stretch full height, the `<summary>` then expands with the `<li>` which I understand but I want the `<summary>` to be full height of the `<li>` all the time (as it could be with a button) but not stretch when it´s open. Is that possible?

Comment: This cannot currently be done with <details> and <summary> using only CSS, because CSS can't manipulate an HTML element's attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click expand with details and summary tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718047/click-expand-with-details-and-summary-tag)

Comment: No it does not answer my question. My question was about how to place the summary and details not how they open and close.