# Accordion open on click & preview on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[Screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg4xF.png)

I am trying to preview the contents of the accordion on hover. Then leave it open on click. I included the code pen. Please help.

https://codepen.io/sarah-omelia/pen/QWdYXMy

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>

<div>
 <button id="acchead" class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  
   <button id="acchead" class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  
  <button id="acchead" class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me, what's the problem?

Comment: **id** must be unique!    ID "ACCHEAD" already defined see https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Seems as you are showing all tags that matches `.accordion-body` try adding another class and selecting the class to properly show, something like `.accordion-body first`, `.accordion-body second` and `accordion-body third`

Comment: Why don't you simply use `<details>` and `<summary>` tags ? it's made for that, with no js coding  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai/56194608#56194608 second part for css customisation

Comment: Ok... Then how do I add multiple sections?

Comment: what do you call *sections* ?  there is no `<section>` tag in your code

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.accordion').forEach(bt=>
  {
  bt.onclick = evt => bt.classList.toggle('active')
  })
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color : #eee;
  color            : #444;
  cursor           : pointer;
  padding          : 18px;
  width            : 100%;
  text-align       : left;
  outline          : none;
  font-size        : 15px;
  transition       : 0.4s;
  padding          : 1em;
  border           : 1px solid blue;
  }
.active, 
.accordion:hover {
  background-color : #ccc;
  }
.accordion:after {
  content          : '\002B';
  color            : #777;
  font-weight      : bold;
  float            : right;
  margin-left      : 5px;
  }
.accordion.active:after {
  content          : '\2212';
  }
.accordion-body {
  border           : 1px solid red;
  max-height       : 0;
  transition       : max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow         : hidden;
  }
.active + div.accordion-body,
.accordion:hover + div.accordion-body {
  max-height       : 500px;
  transition       : max-height 0.25s ease-in;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2>
<p>In this example we have added a "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the "plus" sign is
  replaced with a "minus" sign.</p>

<div>
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Epileptic shock ```alert```.

Comment: @prettyInPink I imagine you think the requested ergonomics is a bad idea? I think so too...

Comment: @SarahO'Melia I find it unfair not to have validated my answer only because the transition values are not what you expected