# How (only by using css without js) to automatically close all the other <details> tags after opening a specific <details> tag

Tags: html, css, accordion, summary

I saw the answer but it was solved by using js. I want to achieve this only by using css.

So I'm making an FAQ accordion with "details" element that would open the answers on clicking on question. What I'm trying to achieve is when I click on some other question to close all other open answers.

Any ideas?

Below is an example.

```
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>
  Demo 1
</details>

<details>
  <summary>2</summary>
  Demo 2
</details>

<details>
  <summary>3</summary>
  Demo 3
</details>
```

Comment: Hey mate I don't think this can be done without using Javascript. There might be a way, but I'd say its better to use Javascript if you wanted that functionality.

Comment: Please can you give more of the code and context. In particular, where are the questions which are clickable in relation to the details which you want open/closed and are they all within one container? I suspect you are going to need JS - can you say why this is problematic?

Comment: The problem with this is twofold in that we're unable - as yet - to select elements that appear prior to an opened `<details>` element, also I  don't believe CSS has a means by which to close an opened element (other than by hiding its descendant elements, but at that point it feels like we're putting accessibility at risk by trying to wrest control of the `<details>` from the HTML element itself. Is there a reason that JavaScript is unavailable to you?

Comment: Probably a duplicate question. The answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai

Answer (score 1):

This, I believe, is as close as you can get:

```css
div > p {
  display: none;
}

div > h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:active > p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Answer 1</h2>
  <p>
    Here's the text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Answer 2</h2>
  <p>
    Here's the text
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Answer 3</h2>
  <p>
    Here's the text
  </p>
</div>
```

Click the title to reveal the answer. The caveat is, as soon as you release the click, the answer immediately hides.