# addEventListener in a for loop in js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to make a for **loop** on an answer block and i want to make the answer have an height of 30px i tried add to the block an event but it didn't work with me, so why?

here is my solution:

HTML code:

```
<div class="blocks block-1">
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <div class="questions">How many team members can I invite?</div>
        <div class="answers">
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is
            no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blocks block-2">
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <div class="questions">What is the maximum file upload size?</div>
        <div class="answers">
            No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted
            storage space.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
const block = document.getElementsByClassName(".blocks");
const answers = document.getElementsByClassName(".answers");

for (i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
    block[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        answers[i].style.height = "30px";
    });
}
```

Comment: @Terry You are wrong!  `toggle` is a native event -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai/56194608#56194608

Comment: i edited the question if you can understand better now..

Comment: +i tryed to use the event "click" but it didn't work too

Comment: oh so i need to add a for loop for it too? or make like answer[i]?

Comment: i tried to make answer[i].style.., but it didn't work too

Comment: @MisterJoJo "toggle" is a native event, that's true, but it's only available on `<details>` elements, from what I can tell (i.e. a bit of research and some brief testing)

Comment: @ADyson at the time of **Terry**'s comment the PO was leaving doubt about the nature of the element. that could very well have been a `<details>` at this time.

Comment: Just remove the dots preceding the cls selectors `entsByClassName("blocks");` their classNames don't have leading dots in their names.

Comment: thank you for helping<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you are looking for this result?

```js
const All_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.blocks');

All_blocks.forEach( blk =>
  {
  blk.addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
    blk.classList.toggle('show_answer')
    })
  })
```

```css
.blocks {
  margin  : .5em;
  padding : .3em;
  }
.questions {
  color  : darkblue;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
.blocks .answers  {
  visibility: hidden;
  }
.blocks.show_answer .answers {
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<div class="blocks block-1">
  <div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="questions">How many team members can I invite?</div>
    <div class="answers">
      You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. 
      There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocks block-2">
  <div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="questions">What is the maximum file upload size?</div>
    <div class="answers">
      No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your 
      allotted storage space.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`answers` is also a collection (just like `block`), so you can't set the style on it directly. But for your case it doesn't really make much sense to look at the whole collection anyway.

If you want to set the style on the `answers` element within the toggled block you need to select it specifically.

Also AFAIK the `toggle` event only works on `<details>` elements. A standard approach to this is to handle the "click" event instead, and switch a class on and off on the element using the `classList.toggle()` function.

Demo:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".blocks");

for (i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {

  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      let answer = this.querySelector(".answers");
      answer.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
}
```

```css
.answers
{
  height:30px;
}

.hidden
{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks block-1">
  <div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="questions">How many team members can I invite?</div>
    <div class="answers hidden">
      You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocks block-2">
  <div class="questionContainer">
    <div class="questions">What is the maximum file upload size?</div>
    <div class="answers hidden">
      No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thanks i will try that then...and i edited the code in my question can you see it and explain why it doesn't work yet?

Comment: Well what result do you get from that edited code precisely? What debugging did you do? It's hard to tell what effect it has because I can't see what CSS/style rules are already set on each answer

Comment: oh i first loop on the block and when the user click on block[i] i want the answer to become form height:0px to height:30px then its will be displayed to the user

Comment: so i use answer[i] because it will be the right answer for block[i] question

Comment: but it didn't work... your method it's better, but i just want to know why my method doesn't work

Comment: Sure - although have you done any debugging / logging  to verify that? but I doubt that's the issue. I expect setting the height by itself doesn't do much. What is the height and display value on each answer _before_ you set it? Have you confirmed the value definitely gets changed after the code runs? TBH my approach really makes more sense anyway - there are clear before/after states and it's done by easily maintainable CSS classes rather than modifying individual style properties with hard coded values

Comment: thank you for helping <3

Answer (score 0):

The firt you want use DOM event, add classList toggle in a NODE. You must distinguish between Dom event and Dom Style. I'm not found DOM Event toggle in w3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

edit:
I try console.log(blocks) for you document.getElementsByClassName(".blocks"). DOM node of have 2 class and result HTMLCollection emty. You must use querySelectorAll

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. It doesn't really provide a solution or even a particularly clear explanation of the problem. Once you have 50 reputation you can add comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).