# how to close an automatically opened accordion tab

Tags: css

I found this great accordion very simple, but I would like when I change tabs, that the one that was open closes automatically
https://codepen.io/TechJohnson/pen/pmJBML

```
<style>
/* Accordion CSS for white dropdown */
.accordion {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordionDrop {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

::-webkit-details-marker { 
  display: none;
}
</style>
<!--Accordion 1-->
<details>
  <summary class="accordion">What is an accordion?</summary>
  
  <div class="accordionDrop">What you just did was click on an accordion. Essentially, an accordion is a graphical control element comprising a vertically stacked list of of items that can be expanded or collapsed to reveal content.</div>
</details>

<!--Accordion 2-->
<details>
  <summary class="accordion">What do you use an accordion for?</summary>
  
  <div class="accordionDrop">An accordion is great for hiding information that you only want to be display when a user is interested. For example: Using an accordion is great on a frequently asked questions page, especially if you have a bunch of questions!</div>
</details>

<!--Accordion 3-->
<details>
  <summary class="accordion">I still need help!</summary>
  
  <div class="accordionDrop">I'm always open to helping you out. If you wish to contact me, my <a href="http://twitter.com/techjohnson">Twitter</a> is always open!</div>
</details>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried to accomplish this? Where are you stuck? What isn't working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically close all the other <details> tags after opening a specific <details> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai)

Comment: Thank you for the answer
when I click on What is an accordion? it opens
But if I click on What do you use an accordion for?
What is an accordion? does not close automatically

Comment: no it does not close the others, when we open another