# JS and CSS code to make foldable elements collapse except active one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've implemented menu for mobile template with unfolding elements.

```
----- 
----- ▼ (folded)
----- ▼ (folded)
----- ▲ (unfolded)
 |----
 |----
 |----
----- ▼ (folded)
----- ▲ (unfolded)
 |----
 |----
 |----
```

Everything is working except of one condition.
After unfolding second menu in a row the other ones should return to default folded state.

```
----- 
----- ▼ (folded)
----- ▼ (folded)
----- ▲ (unfolded)
 |----
 |----
 |----
----- ▼ (folded)
----- ▼ (folded)
```

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-unfold");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.corp-menu-small {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, display 0.4s;
  top: 20%;
  left: 33%;
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav-mobile-overlay {
  display: flex;
}

 :where(.mobile-unfold:nth-child(2n))::after {
  content: url("../../media/svg/arrow-mobile.svg");
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.active::after {
  content: url("../../media/svg/arrow-mobile.svg");
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

.links-unfold-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.links-unfold {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-family: 'FiraSansLight';
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="corp-menu-small">
  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay" href="#">MENU 1</a>
  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay mobile-unfold" href="#">
    MENU 2
        <div class="links-unfold-wrapper"> 
            <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 2/a>
            <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay mobile-unfold" href="# ">MENU 3
    <div class="links-unfold-wrapper"> 
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 2</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 4</a>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay mobile-unfold" href="#">MENU 4
    <div class="links-unfold-wrapper"> 
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 2</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Comment: FYI there's a lot of unnecessary space in your class attributes, which I removed when I built the snippet. Also, yout HTML is invalid. You cannot place a block level element within an inline one - in other words, you can't have a `div` inside an `a`. I'd strongly suggest you use a nested list for this instead

Comment: Might be a good idea to put your code through a validator you can't have anchor elements inside other anchor elements etc. Try for example https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Have you considered using HTML details element with just a little JS to deal with closing the open menus when another one is opened? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai

Comment: Thank you people, stackoverflow is a gold mine for self learner!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method (where I have not adjusted the HTML) to get it working, although it is "hacky" as you are using JS to directly manipulate the styling when it could more easily be controlled with modern CSS and an active class that is toggled.

In the click eventlistener, the first thing that is done is all the menu items are looped through to remove the active classname and all max-heights are reset.
Then the clicked item is marked active and the max-height is adjusted to reveal the submenu.

I would highly recommend re-writing the HTML as Rory and A Haworth have suggested in the comments above, then the resulting CSS/JS would be simplified.

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-unfold");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-unfold").forEach(list => {
      list.classList.remove("active");
      list.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = '0';
    });
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
.corp-menu-small {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, display 0.4s;
  top: 20%;
  left: 33%;
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav-mobile-overlay {
  display: flex;
}

 :where(.mobile-unfold:nth-child(2n))::after {
  content: url("../../media/svg/arrow-mobile.svg");
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.active::after {
  content: url("../../media/svg/arrow-mobile.svg");
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

.links-unfold-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.links-unfold {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-family: 'FiraSansLight';
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="corp-menu-small">
  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay" href="#">MENU 1</a>
  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay mobile-unfold" href="#">
    MENU 2
        <div class="links-unfold-wrapper"> 
            <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 2/a>
            <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay mobile-unfold" href="# ">MENU 3
    <div class="links-unfold-wrapper"> 
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 2</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 4</a>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="menu nav-mobile-overlay mobile-unfold" href="#">MENU 4
    <div class="links-unfold-wrapper"> 
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 1</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 2</a>
      <a class="menu links-unfold" href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Comment: Thanks you guys! It's working.
I'll try to simplify construction.