Creating buttons that hide their respective paragraph
I have 3 buttons and 3 paragraphs. I want to create a js function that hides all paragraphs except the one with the same letter as the button, using a CSS rule that apply the class "hidden".
I tried many things but all I can do is to toggle the class hidden to all paragraphs. Can someone explain me how I can do that please?


function toggle(clicked, id) {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
  var length = el.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    el[i].classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<div class="button">
  <button class="a" onClick="toggle(this,id)">a</button>
  <button class="b" onClick="toggle(this,id)">b</button>
  <button class="c" onClick="toggle(this,id)">c</button>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="a text">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="b text">
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="c text">
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
</div>




It seems you are confusing the CSS properties display:none; and visibility:hidden;

Hey Mister Jojo, if I understand how it works, display "remove" the block from the flow of the page, while visibility just hide it, but leave the blank space where the element is supposed to be. Am I right? Because the result I am expecting is to have no blank space left when showing the different paragraphs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

This question is similar to: Is there a shorter more concise way to hide & show div with Javascript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@EnzoFillon what Mister Jojo was referring to was the class name. Call the class d-none which would explain to everyone what this class does. A class called hidden throws the expectation that the element is hidden (visibility: hidden).

@tacoshy Oh I see, it makes sense :) Sorry if it is confusing, first of all I'm french and also this is my first post on the website

Please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments are discouraged. Respond to clarifying questions by updating your question post. Respond to helpful answers with votes and acceptance. Notice how I simplified your post and created a demo with your code.

If you really want to solve this with JavaScript and not find the linked duplicate useful then this answer will help you. If it indeed is a duplicate then please just mark it as duplicate and the question and this answer will be auto deleted in 30 days.
In modern JavaScript, you should split HTML and JS apart. The reason is, that JS can be cached and reused for other HTML pages. Besides that, keeping HTML and JS strictly linked together by using the onclick attribute, changes would have to be made in both files which makes maintenance way harder than doing changes only in one place. As such you should use addEventListener.
First, you should reference all the buttons you want to have. You can do this by using querySelectorAll. That returns a Node List which is an array-like object. As an object it does not return a single element but a list of elements. As such you always need to use an iteration method to loop through the list (for-loop, forEach, etc.).
You can use this in the first instance to add an event listener to all those buttons and add an anonymous function (a function without a name very similar to lambda). Then you read out something from the button like a data-attribute that contains the id of the element you like to target.
After that, you loop through the paragraphs (the same way as above with the buttons). You can use classList.toggle('class', statement) to apply the class to all elements where the statement is true and remove it from the elements where the statement is not true.


const BUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const PARAGRAPHS = document.querySelectorAll('p');

BUTTONS.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    PARAGRAPHS.forEach(paragraph => {
      paragraph.classList.toggle('d-none', paragraph.id !== this.dataset.id)
    })
  })
})
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
  <button data-id="paraA">A</button>
  <button data-id="paraB">B</button>
  <button data-id="paraC">C</button>
  <br>
  <p id="paraA">A</p>
  <p id="paraB">B</p>
  <p id="paraC">C</p>




Thanks for your answer! I don't understand everything but I will do some research on internet to understand. I prefer using js for the moment so the answer you linked is really interesting, but it is not an answer I will use in my case. I appreciated your help, thank you again.

FYI, duplicates are never hit by Roomba if they are scored >= 0 or if they have any answers.

@miken32 I know but I'm in the review team. We close or del questions manually then.

Instead of classes, you should store state as a data attribute.
You can link an element i.e. data-toggle and element i.e. data-ref.


function toggle(event) {
  const { toggle } = event.target.dataset;
  if (!toggle) return;
  toggleClass(`[data-ref="${toggle}"]`, 'hidden');
}

function toggleClass(elementOrSelector, className) {
  const el = typeof elementOrSelector === 'string'
    ? document.querySelector(elementOrSelector)
    : elementOrSelector;
  el.classList.toggle(className);
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<div class="button">
  <button data-toggle="a" onClick="toggle(event)">a</button>
  <button data-toggle="b" onClick="toggle(event)">b</button>
  <button data-toggle="c" onClick="toggle(event)">c</button>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="text" data-ref="a">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text" data-ref="b">
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text" data-ref="c">
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
</div>




⭐Update
I'm not totally sure if the OP wanted either:

Each <button>/<p> pair to toggle independently...
OR...

One <button>/<p> pair is shown while the others are hidden. That behavior is called mutual exclusivity.


So I added a version of each that exhibits mutual exclusivity.
Below are six examples. The first four examples are JavaScript and employ Event Delegation. The last two examples use only CSS. Details are commented in the examples.
Finding Index of Clicked <button> with .indexOf()


/*
  Reference an ancestor element that all <button>s share in 
  common (ex. <main> or <menu>).
*/
const main = document.querySelector("main");
// Collect all <p>s in <main> into an array
const text = [...main.querySelectorAll("p")];
// Collect all <button>s in <main> into an array
const btns = [...main.querySelectorAll("button")];

/**
 * Design event handler to delegate events for all of the children
 * elements of the registered ancestor element (ex. <main>).
 * Only have it act on specific elements (ex. <button>s) while
 * ignoring everything else.
 */
function toggleText(event) {
  /*
    event.target property references the element the user triggered
    an registered event on (ex. "click", "mouseover", "input", etc.). 
    If the user clicked a <button>...
  */
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    // find the index of the <button> the user clicked...
    let index = btns.indexOf(event.target);
    // then find the paragraph that matches that index
    text[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
}
/*
  Register <main> to listen for the "click" event for all of it's
  children elements (and itself as well).
*/
main.addEventListener("click", toggleText);
:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.3 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 12ch;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  width: 65vw; 
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  height: 1ex;
  margin: 0.25ex 4px 0 0;
  font: 4rem/0.3 "Lucida Sans";
  color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<main>
  <menu>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
  </menu>
  <article>
    <p class="hidden">Abstract enlightenment value revaluation ocean god christianity superiority value free spirit ideal moral. Justice christianity depths intentions inexpedient ubermensch overcome marvelous zarathustra depths victorious good. Will justice value play
      chaos selfish society truth. Oneself good hope will mountains endless salvation joy ultimate philosophy. Chaos endless justice suicide evil inexpedient war disgust. Superiority dead philosophy law philosophy pious law sea aversion evil.</p>

    <p class="hidden">Burying law victorious burying chaos faith good self good moral battle. Philosophy ubermensch free reason endless reason truth gains play horror aversion madness madness. Marvelous mountains mountains good eternal-return pious society play merciful
      moral abstract decrepit. War ocean hatred pious ascetic free aversion fearful truth enlightenment noble superiority oneself.</p>

    <p class="hidden">Chaos free holiest christianity chaos selfish contradict derive oneself hope against. Strong snare hatred superiority evil madness will pious ultimate law derive eternal-return convictions. Against free reason battle right sexuality.</p>
  </article>
</main>



Mutually Exclusive Version


/**
 * Changes are denoted with a ⭐
 */
/*
  Reference an ancestor element that all <button>s share in 
  common (ex. <main> or <menu>).
*/
const main = document.querySelector("main");
// Collect all <p>s in <main> into an array
const text = [...main.querySelectorAll("p")];
// Collect all <button>s in <main> into an array
const btns = [...main.querySelectorAll("button")];

/**
 * Design event handler to delegate events for all of the children
 * elements of the registered ancestor element (ex. <main>).
 * Only have it act on specific elements (ex. <button>s) while
 * ignoring everything else.
 */
function toggleText(event) {
  /*
    event.target property references the element the user triggered
    an registered event on (ex. "click", "mouseover", "input", etc.). 
    If the user clicked a <button>...
  */
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    // find the index of the <button> the user clicked...
    let index = btns.indexOf(event.target);
    // ⭐
    // iterate through the array of <p>s and hide all of them...
    text.forEach(p => p.classList.add("hidden"));
    // ⭐ 
    // then find the paragraph that matches that index
    text[index].classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
/*
  Register <main> to listen for the "click" event for all of it's
  children elements (and itself as well).
*/
main.addEventListener("click", toggleText);
:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.3 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 12ch;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  width: 65vw; 
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  height: 1ex;
  margin: 0.25ex 4px 0 0;
  font: 4rem/0.3 "Lucida Sans";
  color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<main>
  <menu>
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
  </menu>
  <article>
    <p class="hidden">Abstract enlightenment value revaluation ocean god christianity superiority value free spirit ideal moral. Justice christianity depths intentions inexpedient ubermensch overcome marvelous zarathustra depths victorious good. Will justice value play
      chaos selfish society truth. Oneself good hope will mountains endless salvation joy ultimate philosophy. Chaos endless justice suicide evil inexpedient war disgust. Superiority dead philosophy law philosophy pious law sea aversion evil.</p>

    <p class="hidden">Burying law victorious burying chaos faith good self good moral battle. Philosophy ubermensch free reason endless reason truth gains play horror aversion madness madness. Marvelous mountains mountains good eternal-return pious society play merciful
      moral abstract decrepit. War ocean hatred pious ascetic free aversion fearful truth enlightenment noble superiority oneself.</p>

    <p class="hidden">Chaos free holiest christianity chaos selfish contradict derive oneself hope against. Strong snare hatred superiority evil madness will pious ultimate law derive eternal-return convictions. Against free reason battle right sexuality.</p>
  </article>
</main>




Matching Indexes with data-* Attributes


// Reference an ancestor element that all of the <button>s have in common
const main = document.querySelector("main");

/*
  The event handler should act only for specific elements 
  (ex <button>s) and ignore the rest.
*/
function toggleText(event) {
  /*
    event.target references the <button> the user clicked.
    If the user clicked a <button>...
  */
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    // get the <button>'s index...
    let index = event.target.dataset.idx;
    // then find the <p> with the matching [data-idx]...
    const p = document.querySelector(`p[data-idx="${index}"]`);
    // and toggle it's .hidden class
    p.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
}
/*
  Register <main> to listen for the "click" event for all of it's
  children elements.
*/
main.addEventListener("click", toggleText);
:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.3 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 12ch;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  width: 65vw; 
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  height: 1ex;
  margin: 0.25ex 4px 0 0;
  font: 4rem/0.3 "Lucida Sans";
  color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<main>
  <!-- 
    Each <button> has a [data-idx] attribute with a value that
    corresponds with it's index of 0, 1, and 2 
  -->
  <menu>
    <button data-idx="0">A</button>
    <button data-idx="1">B</button>
    <button data-idx="2">C</button>
  </menu>
  <!--
    Each <p> also has a [data-idx] attribute with an index of 0, 1, and 2
  -->
  <article>
    <p class="hidden" data-idx="0">Abstract enlightenment value revaluation ocean god christianity superiority value free spirit ideal moral. Justice christianity depths intentions inexpedient ubermensch overcome marvelous zarathustra depths victorious good. Will justice value play
      chaos selfish society truth. Oneself good hope will mountains endless salvation joy ultimate philosophy. Chaos endless justice suicide evil inexpedient war disgust. Superiority dead philosophy law philosophy pious law sea aversion evil.</p>

    <p class="hidden" data-idx="1">Burying law victorious burying chaos faith good self good moral battle. Philosophy ubermensch free reason endless reason truth gains play horror aversion madness madness. Marvelous mountains mountains good eternal-return pious society play merciful
      moral abstract decrepit. War ocean hatred pious ascetic free aversion fearful truth enlightenment noble superiority oneself.</p>

    <p class="hidden" data-idx="2">Chaos free holiest christianity chaos selfish contradict derive oneself hope against. Strong snare hatred superiority evil madness will pious ultimate law derive eternal-return convictions. Against free reason battle right sexuality.</p>
  </article>
</main>



Mutually Exclusive Version


/**
 * Changes are denoted with a ⭐
 */
// Reference an ancestor element that all of the <button>s have in common
const main = document.querySelector("main");

/*
  The event handler should act only for specific elements 
  (ex <button>s) and ignore the rest.
*/
function toggleText(event) {
  /*
    event.target references the <button> the user clicked.
    If the user clicked a <button>...
  */
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    // ⭐
    // collect <p>s into an array and hide each one...
    [...this.querySelectorAll("p")].forEach(p => p.classList.add("hidden"));
    // get the <button>'s index...
    let index = event.target.dataset.idx;
    // then find the <p> with the matching [data-idx]...
    const p = document.querySelector(`p[data-idx="${index}"]`);
    // ⭐
    // and toggle it's .hidden class
    p.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
/*
  Register <main> to listen for the "click" event for all of it's
  children elements.
*/
main.addEventListener("click", toggleText);
:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.3 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 12ch;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  width: 65vw; 
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  height: 1ex;
  margin: 0.25ex 4px 0 0;
  font: 4rem/0.3 "Lucida Sans";
  color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<main>
  <!-- 
    Each <button> has a [data-idx] attribute with a value that
    corresponds with it's index of 0, 1, and 2 
  -->
  <menu>
    <button data-idx="0">A</button>
    <button data-idx="1">B</button>
    <button data-idx="2">C</button>
  </menu>
  <!--
    Each <p> also has a [data-idx] attribute with an index of 0, 1, and 2
  -->
  <article>
    <p class="hidden" data-idx="0">Abstract enlightenment value revaluation ocean god christianity superiority value free spirit ideal moral. Justice christianity depths intentions inexpedient ubermensch overcome marvelous zarathustra depths victorious good. Will justice value play
      chaos selfish society truth. Oneself good hope will mountains endless salvation joy ultimate philosophy. Chaos endless justice suicide evil inexpedient war disgust. Superiority dead philosophy law philosophy pious law sea aversion evil.</p>

    <p class="hidden" data-idx="1">Burying law victorious burying chaos faith good self good moral battle. Philosophy ubermensch free reason endless reason truth gains play horror aversion madness madness. Marvelous mountains mountains good eternal-return pious society play merciful
      moral abstract decrepit. War ocean hatred pious ascetic free aversion fearful truth enlightenment noble superiority oneself.</p>

    <p class="hidden" data-idx="2">Chaos free holiest christianity chaos selfish contradict derive oneself hope against. Strong snare hatred superiority evil madness will pious ultimate law derive eternal-return convictions. Against free reason battle right sexuality.</p>
  </article>
</main>




CSS Only Using <label for="ID"></label> 
and <input id="ID" type="checkbox" hidden> Elements


:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.3 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*
  Each <label> is styled to appear as a <button>
*/
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12ch;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border: 1px black outset;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: buttonface;
}

p {
  width: 65vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  height: 1ex;
  margin: 0.25ex 4px 0 0;
  font: 4rem/0.3 "Lucida Sans";
  color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/*
  Each <input type="checkbox"> when :checked shows the hidden
  <p> that is directly after it. + is a sibling combinator that
  indicates that the <p> follows the <input type="checkbox">
*/
[type="checkbox"]:checked+p {
  display: block;
}
<main>
  <!--
    Each <label> has a [for] attribute with a value that corresponds
    to an <input type="checkbox"> [id]. Whenever a <label> is 
    clicked the corresponding <input type="checkbox"> gets
    un/checked (toggled). The :checked pseudo-class in CSS acts
    as a switch that can change any styles of any element that 
    follows the <input type="checkbox">.
  -->
  <menu>
    <label for="A">A</label>
    <label for="B">B</label>
    <label for="C">C</label>
  </menu>
  <!--
    Each <input type="checkbox"> has a [hidden] attribute and is
    positioned in front of a <p>. When :checked the <p> will
    be assigned display: block
  -->
  <article>
    <input id="A" type="checkbox" hidden>
    <p class="hidden">Abstract enlightenment value revaluation ocean god christianity superiority value free spirit ideal moral. Justice christianity depths intentions inexpedient ubermensch overcome marvelous zarathustra depths victorious good. Will justice value play
      chaos selfish society truth. Oneself good hope will mountains endless salvation joy ultimate philosophy. Chaos endless justice suicide evil inexpedient war disgust. Superiority dead philosophy law philosophy pious law sea aversion evil.</p>

    <input id="B" type="checkbox" hidden>
    <p class="hidden">Burying law victorious burying chaos faith good self good moral battle. Philosophy ubermensch free reason endless reason truth gains play horror aversion madness madness. Marvelous mountains mountains good eternal-return pious society play merciful
      moral abstract decrepit. War ocean hatred pious ascetic free aversion fearful truth enlightenment noble superiority oneself.</p>

    <input id="C" type="checkbox" hidden>
    <p class="hidden">Chaos free holiest christianity chaos selfish contradict derive oneself hope against. Strong snare hatred superiority evil madness will pious ultimate law derive eternal-return convictions. Against free reason battle right sexuality.</p>
  </article>
</main>



Mutually Exclusive Version 
with <input id="ID" name="rads" type="radio" hidden>


/**
 * Changes are denoted with a ⭐
 */
:root {
  font: 1.5ch/1.3 "Segoe UI";
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

menu {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*
  Each <label> is styled to appear as a <button>
*/
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12ch;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border: 1px black outset;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: buttonface;
}

p {
  width: 65vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

p::first-letter {
  float: left;
  height: 1ex;
  margin: 0.25ex 4px 0 0;
  font: 4rem/0.3 "Lucida Sans";
  color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* ⭐ */
/*
  Each <input type="radio"> when :checked shows the hidden
  <p> that is directly after it. + is a sibling combinator that
  indicates that the <p> follows the <input type="radio">
*/
[type="radio"]:checked+p {
  display: block;
}
<!-- 
  Changes are denoted with a ⭐
-->
<main>
  <!--
    Each <label> has a [for] attribute with a value that corresponds
    to an <input type="radio"> [id]. Whenever a <label> is 
    clicked the corresponding <input type="radio"> gets
    un/checked (toggled). The :checked pseudo-class in CSS acts
    as a switch that can change any styles of any element that 
    follows the <input type="radio">.
  -->
  <menu>
    <label for="A">A</label>
    <label for="B">B</label>
    <label for="C">C</label>
  </menu>
  <!-- ⭐ -->
  <!--
    Each <input type="radio"> has a [hidden] attribute and is
    positioned in front of a <p>. When :checked the <p> will
    be assigned display: block
    In order for the <input type="radio">s to be mutually exclusive
    add a [name] attribute to each one with the same value:
    ex. name="rads"
  -->
  <article>
    <input id="A" name="rads" type="radio" hidden>
    <p class="hidden">Abstract enlightenment value revaluation ocean god christianity superiority value free spirit ideal moral. Justice christianity depths intentions inexpedient ubermensch overcome marvelous zarathustra depths victorious good. Will justice value play
      chaos selfish society truth. Oneself good hope will mountains endless salvation joy ultimate philosophy. Chaos endless justice suicide evil inexpedient war disgust. Superiority dead philosophy law philosophy pious law sea aversion evil.</p>

    <input id="B" name="rads" type="radio" hidden>
    <p class="hidden">Burying law victorious burying chaos faith good self good moral battle. Philosophy ubermensch free reason endless reason truth gains play horror aversion madness madness. Marvelous mountains mountains good eternal-return pious society play merciful
      moral abstract decrepit. War ocean hatred pious ascetic free aversion fearful truth enlightenment noble superiority oneself.</p>

    <input id="C" name="rads" type="radio" hidden>
    <p class="hidden">Chaos free holiest christianity chaos selfish contradict derive oneself hope against. Strong snare hatred superiority evil madness will pious ultimate law derive eternal-return convictions. Against free reason battle right sexuality.</p>
  </article>
</main>




I absolutely love the last JS-free example of yours. Looking at the code, it's so obvious that it offers the by far best possible solution (technically and by elegance) to the OP's problem.

@EnzoFillon ... The above answer should be the accepted one for it offers a variety of approaches, each being reasonable, and each coming with a rock-solid implementation.

It could be done in a quite simple way using the details element, with the use of his open attribute.
Further enhancement can be done by using CSS!


document.body.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach((e) => e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   document.body.querySelectorAll('details').forEach((e) => (e.hasAttribute('open')) ? e.removeAttribute('open') : '')
}))
<details>
    <summary>A</summary>
    A content
</details>

<details>
    <summary>B</summary>
    B content
</details>

<details>
    <summary>C</summary>
    C content
</details>



Source

Thank you for your answer! I will try this too, but is your code using JQuery? I don't really understand how to use it for the moment but your answer helps me to improve my skills anyway, so thank you again!

This is regular JavaScript, there is no need to install any libraries, this is universal.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751345/automatically-close-all-the-other-details-tags-after-opening-a-specific-detai/56194608#56194608

If you really, really want what is given in the question, that is, the content of the button to be the same as the content of the paragraph that is to be shown, then here is a snippet that does that, with some explanation in the comments:


<head>
  <style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <br>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <script>
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');

    function hideAllPs() {
      ps.forEach((p) => {
        p.classList.add('hidden');
      });
    }
    //a function to find a p element that has the given text
    function findPWithSameText(text) {
      let el;
      //look at each p element until you find one with the same text
      ps.forEach((p) => {
        if (p.innerText == text) {
          el = p;
        }
      });
      return el;
    }
    // start off by hiding all the p elements
    hideAllPs();
    //add a listener to each button to sense when it is clicked 
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        hideAllPs();
        findPWithSameText(button.innerText).classList.remove('hidden');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>



However, as others have pointed out, this is not a very fruitful exercise as the text is visible already in the button, so revealing the paragraph with exactly the same text is not very useful to the reader.
Several other methods have been shown to you so I won't repeat them, but basically you find a way to link the button to its paragraph, which may be by using details or may be by putting the paragraph immediately after the button or may be by linking through say a class, id or data- value etc.

First the direct question: You can simply toggle a class in the classList on a node here like this myTarget.classList.toggle('hidden', this.toggleClass && false);  See that in use in the code below with a true and false value -
I also put in a this.toggleClass to basically turn this on/off with a button; why? This also lends itself to some "fun" here.
You basically have three elements you want to toggle as showing or not.  Three sounds like a stoplight so for fun let's also toggle the three like a stoplight - so we have three elements each with a red/yellow/green color and toggle for that.  Use the Toggle Class Use button to swap from stoplight to the show/hide dynamically.
Here I also use a JavaScript class with lots of comments but really just to contain my code to an instance and keep the selector text associated with my "containers" for the buttons and the results/toggled values.  The handleClick function does all the hard work but note how I bound that to the class instance for this for ease of use etc.


/* declare our class - no "super" class on this one */
class MyToggleClass {
  // private fields
  #rawSelector = ".toggle-raw";

  // public class fields with default value
  toggleSelector = ".toggle-button";
  toggleTargetSelector = ".item-text";
  mainSelector = ".main-container";

  /* the constructor method, always named "constructor" */
  constructor(toggleElementSelector, showLogs) {
    this.showConsoleLogs = showLogs;
    // bind the class to the click hander method "handleClick" as "this"
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.toggleSelector = toggleElementSelector;
  }

  trafficLightOff() {
    document.querySelectorAll(this.toggleTargetSelector)
      .forEach((element, nodeIndex) => {
        const toggleValue = "false";
        element.dataset.toggle = toggleValue;
        element.style.backgroundColor = element.closest(this.mainSelector).dataset.colorOff;
        // Note we could ALSO toggle the class  - this is the OP question
        element.classList.toggle('hidden', this.toggleClass && true);
      });
  }

  // method to handle the click event we will attach
  handleClick(event, elementSelector, extraData) {
    if(this.showConsoleLogs) {
      console.log('clicked something', extraData);
    }
    const thisNodeIndex = extraData.nodeIndex * 1 + 1;
    const nodeSelector = ':nth-of-type(' + thisNodeIndex + ')';
    // related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/how-to-select-the-first-second-or-third-element-with-a-given-class-name
    const meSel = elementSelector + nodeSelector;
    const me = document.querySelector(meSel);
    if (this.showConsoleLogs) { 
       console.log('clicked', extraData, meSel);
    }

    if (me == event.target) {
      this.trafficLightOff();
      const myTargetSelector = extraData.targetSelector + nodeSelector;
      const myTarget =  document.querySelector(this.mainSelector)
        .querySelector(myTargetSelector);
      let dataToggle = myTarget.dataset.toggle;
      const toggleValue = dataToggle == "true" ? "false" : "true";
      myTarget.dataset.toggle = toggleValue;
      // toggle the class - this is the OP question
      myTarget.classList.toggle('hidden', this.toggleClass && false);
      myTarget.style.backgroundColor = myTarget.dataset.color;
    }
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    if (this.showConsoleLogs) {
      console.log('adding listeners',this.toggleSelector,(this.showConsoleLogs && this.verboseLogs));
    }
    document.querySelectorAll(this.toggleSelector)
      .forEach((togElement, index) => {
         if (this.showConsoleLogs && this.verboseLogs) { 
           console.log('adding listener', togElement,index);
         }
       const extraData = { value: 10, targetSelector: this.toggleTargetSelector, nodeIndex: index };
       if (this.showConsoleLogs && this.verboseLogs) { 
         console.log("extraData:", extraData);
       }
       togElement.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          this.handleClick(event, this.toggleSelector, extraData);
        });
      }); // end of forEach
  } // end of addEventListeners
}

const showConsoleLogs = false;

// create a class instance 
const myClass = new MyToggleClass(".toggle-button", showConsoleLogs);

//set a new class property
myClass.verboseLogs = false;
myClass.toggleClass = true;
 
//call method to add listeners in our new class intance
myClass.addEventListeners();

//use our class properties to get the toggle buttons
const toggleButtons = document.querySelector(myClass.mainSelector)
  .querySelectorAll(myClass.toggleSelector);

const toggleClassButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-class-hidden');
toggleClassButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
   myClass.toggleClass = myClass.toggleClass ? false : true; 
   event.target.querySelector('.class-toggle-flag').textContent = `:(" ${myClass.toggleClass} ")`;
});
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}

.button-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #0000ff10;
}

.toggle-button {
  width: 4em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.item-text{
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.item-text[data-toggle="true"]{
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid blue 4px;
}
.toggle-class-hidden {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: block;
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button type="button" class="toggle-button a">a</button>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-button b">b</button>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-button c">c</button>
  <span>These will target the elements in the main container by index</span>
</div>

<div class="main main-container" data-color-off="#555363a0">
  <div class="a item-text" data-color="#d20303">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b item-text" data-color="#cbb100">
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c item-text" data-color="#12ae00">
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="toggle-class-hidden">Toggle Class Use<span class="class-toggle-flag"></span></button>




There are alternative approaches to the OP's problem.
Thanks to the meanwhile widely supported functional  :has() CSS pseudo-class, a menu or selector which exists independently (not nested) from the to be targeted structure can be achieved exclusively with HTML and CSS.


/**
 *  - inside the `main-options` classified
 *    container hide every element with the
 *    `data-option` attribute.
 */
.main-options {
  [data-option] {
    display: none;
  }
}

.main-selector {
  /**
   *  - inside the `main-selector` classified
   *    container emulate a button appearance
   *    for every radio-control ...
   */
  label {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0 4px 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #eee;

    > [type="radio"] {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }

    /**
     *  ... where a checked/selected
     *  button is indicated properly.
     */
    &:has(:checked) {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  - inside the `main-options` classified
   *    container which does proceed (~) the
   *    `main-selector` container do display
   *    every element with the `data-option`
   *    attribute in case its attribute value
   *    equals the value of its related and
   *    checked radio-control where the latter
   *    resides inside the `main-selector`
   *    classified container.
   */

  &:has([value="a"]:checked) {
    ~ .main-options {
      [data-option="a"] {
        display: revert;
      }
    }
  }
  &:has([value="b"]:checked) {
    ~ .main-options {
      [data-option="b"] {
        display: revert;
      }
    }
  }
  &:has([value="c"]:checked) {
    ~ .main-options {
      [data-option="c"] {
        display: revert;
      }
    }
  }
}
<div class="main-selector">
  <label>
    <span>a</span>
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="option" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>b</span>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="option" checked />
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>c</span>
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="option" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="main-options">
  <div class="text" data-option="a">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="text" data-option="b">
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text" data-option="c">
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
</div>



An even older and already approved approach which for more than a decate successfully solves exactly that kind of problem ...

OP: "I want to create a js function that hides all paragraphs except the one with the same letter as the button"

... would make use of the :target CSS pseudo-class ...


article {
  section[id] {

    display: none;

    &:target {

      display: revert;
    }
  }
}
nav {
  a[href^="#"] {

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 8px 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &:visited {

      color: #000;
    }
  }
}
<nav>
  <a href="#a">a</a>
  <a href="#b">b</a>
  <a href="#c">c</a>
</nav>

<article>
  <section id="a">
    <p>a</p>
  </section>

  <section id="b">
    <p>b</p>
  </section>

  <section id="c">
    <p>c</p>
  </section>
</article>



